# Неекранированный текст

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Я уже не знаю,что с этим делать. Мне надо достать содержимое пост в вордпресс и использовать его в джаваскрипте. 
Вордпресс возвращает неэкраннированный текст. Вот это я скопировал из браузера

```
 document.getElementById('qua').innerHTML="<p>Lorem ipsum dolor slksf;lgsit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br />
tempor incididuknt ut labore et dolohhhrelk;kllk magnat aliq. Ut enim ad minim veniam,<br />
quis nostrud exercitation ullamcj<br />
is jyuyynisi ut aliquip ex ea  commodo<br />
consequat. Duis aute irur dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse<br />
cillum dolore eu fikugiat nulla pariaturl;. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non<br />
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p> <a href="http://wordpress/2016/11/04/peppa-pig-playing-in-a-bog/#more-9" class="more-link"><span aria-label="Читать далее Peppa pig playing in a bog">(далее&hellip;)</span></a></p>
"
```

Comment: А как вам его нужно использовать в js?

Comment: ну экранируйте его перед выводом, если вам это необходимо. `echo addcslashes(get_the_content());`

Comment: мне возвращают текст в несколько строк, а надо в одну или добавить в  каждую обратный слеш

Comment: Сделайте замену перевода строк, добавьте слеши - не увидел проблемы

Comment: str_replace, addslashes или htmlspecialchars в зависимости от нужд